# can't connect gopro to my gentoo

Tags: mount, gopro

I want to download the files from my GoPro Hero5 Session, but I can't mount it to my laptop. When I connect the camera, the logs detect a new device (pasted below), but nothing appears in `/dev/sd*`, so I can't even try to mount it manually. I have FUSE enabled in kernel (for example sshfs works), and `exfat-utils` and `fuse-exfat` installed. What can I do to debug this further?

I can connect to the GoPro's wifi, but I still want to be able to mount int normally for faster transfer.

The GoPro is fully updated.
Running gentoo with kernel 4.10.1. 
Logs from connecting the camera:

```
Jul  8 09:29:02 <hostname> kernel: usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Jul  8 09:29:02 <hostname> kernel: usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2672, idProduct=0029
Jul  8 09:29:02 <hostname> kernel: usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul  8 09:29:02 <hostname> kernel: usb 3-2: Product: StillImage
Jul  8 09:29:02 <hostname> kernel: usb 3-2: Manufacturer: GoPro
Jul  8 09:29:02 <hostname> kernel: usb 3-2: SerialNumber: C3211354591265
Jul  8 09:29:02 <hostname> mtp-probe[19780]: checking bus 3, device 6: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2"
Jul  8 09:29:02 <hostname> mtp-probe[19780]: bus: 3, device: 6 was not an MTP device
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to connect to the camera using `gphoto2` from terminal, and also using `gphotofs` to browse the files.

I probably was wrong thinking it should appear in `/dev/sd*` in the first place, maybe that was true for some other models. This camera must use another protocol.